# How to post link variables with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a link something likes this..

```
<a href="p_p.cfm?id=#user.id#">
```

I want to post `id` variable (`#user.id#`) with `p_p.cfm` ...

I have tried so many times with my code but nothing happens :(

Comment: '$("a#link").click(function(){

    $.post("p_p.cfm",
       {
         $(this).attr("user_id")
       },
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       }
    );

    return false;
});'

Comment: are you trying to pass the variable `user.id` to `id` parameter of page `p_p.cfm` ?

Comment: Yep ! i want to post #user.id# value with p_p.cfm

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
$('#link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var params = this.href.split('?');
    $.post(params[0], params[1]).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Will issue POST request to `p_p.cfm` with parameters `id=xxx` (will be URL encoded by jQuery automatically).

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Njs7W/

<sup>(open dev tools and examine 404 request params)</sup>

Comment: It should not. Did you add `e.preventDefault();` or `return false`?

Comment: Ah no ! is it important?

Comment: Of course. By default it navigates to another page. By `preventDefault` of `return false` you say browser not to redirect.

Comment: Got it bro ! Thanks once again !:)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, you have user object with id property, which you are trying to pass to the query parameter id of the page p_p.cfm

Do this:

```
<a id="someId" href="#"></a>

$(function(){
$('#someId').attr("href","p_p.cfm?id="+user.id);
});
```